# copy cells based on a dynamic number

Tags: excel, vba

So I am working on a much larger project and I have hit a wall. Right now I have a list of items, and what I need to do is copy them from one sheet and paste them to another, but it needs to have an offset.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtdlp.jpg

So what I need to happen is that the code looks at reglatory name and matches it to another sheet.  Then in that sheet it has the values that are to be passed in under the key. I can copy the values over and loop it to be x number of times, but how do I get the loop number to match a specific field in the data set?

The second thing is once the network unit name and reglatory name is copied over and sorted, how do I then copy the key which is the country field field code?  Can I name that table value as a variable?

```
Sub Main()
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim LR As Long
 Dim I as long
 LastRow = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

For I= 1 to 'Dynamic range from key count'
    Sheet8.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 3)).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("ALR:CLR" & LastRow)
    LR=Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
Next I   
 'autosort sub'

End Sub
```

Any help in help flushing this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So..you want to copy the cell ranges with "country,Field,...,Well Number" over to the `Key` field on another sheet for each unit name?? Finding it hard to follow. Can you provide an example? I don't know what `Sheet1` and `Sheet8` are in your image, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Data We Pull From").Range("A2:A12")
Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Finished Product").Range("A2")
Set rngList = Worksheets("How Much We Need to Offset By").Range("A1:A12")

For Each tmpCell In rngSource
    rngTarget.Resize(12, 3).Value = tmpCell.Resize(1, 3).Value
    rngTarget.Offset(, 3).Resize(12).Value = rngList.Value
    Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(12)
Next tmpCell
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really transcribe your code to a working sample as there is too much that has been redacted out but I believe I understand what you are asking. Here are some abstract examples.

With your field list in Sheet1 starting at K5, this will store the values into an array.

```
Dim vFLDs As Variant
With Sheet1
    vFLDs = .Range(.Range("K5"), .Range("K5").End(xlDown))
End With
```

You do not have to loop the copy of the *reglatory name* (sp?) data, simply expand the destination to the number of row within `vFLDs`.

```
Sheet8.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 3)).Copy _
  Destination:=Sheet1.Range("ALR:CLR" & LastRow).Resize(UBound(vFLDs), 1)
```

Finally, transfer the values in `vFLDs` to the last column.

```
Sheet1.Range(<the next empty column> & LastRow).Resize(UBound(vFLDs), 1) = vFLDs
```